# How to do fitting for each subsets of data and plot their fitting curves?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

Actually I have done much of the thing before I ask here and done lots of search but couldn't find the solution so far.

I have a subset of data that I need to fit each subset. On the other hand, when I try to plot regression lines of each of these subsets only one regression line is shown on the plot. That is the main problem so far.

Anyway lets go step by step;
here is a `data.frame`

```
   xx <- rep(rep(seq(0,800,200),each=10),times=2)
   yy<-c(replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-1,0),decreasing=TRUE)),replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-1,0),decreasing=TRUE)), replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-2,0),decreasing=TRUE)),replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-3,0),decreasing=TRUE)), replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-4,0), decreasing=TRUE)))    
   V <- rep(seq(100,2500,length.out=10),times=2)
   No <- rep(1:10,each=10)
   df <- data.frame(V,xx,yy,No)
```

from wide format to long format

```
library(reshape2)
df_new <- melt(df,id=c("No","xx","V"))
```

**fitting model

```
As <- 220
Ax <- 1500
 
  model <- function(data){
  nlsLM(value~ifelse(V<Vs, 1-exp(-D*(1-(xx-As)/Ax)^2*(1-V/Vs)^2),1),
        data=data, start=c(D=1.21,Vs=1951),trace=T,control = nls.lm.control(maxiter=50))
}



library(plyr)
library(minpack.lm)

fit<- dlply(df_new, "No", .fun = model)
```

function for predicting fitting values ##from [Adding Fitted Lines from an Existing Model](https://rpubs.com/escott8908/RGC_Ch5_Scatter_Plots)

```
predictvals <- function(model, xvar, yvar, xrange=NULL, samples=10, ...) {
  # If xrange isn't passed in, determine xrange from the models.
  # Different ways of extracting the x range, depending on model type
  if (is.null(xrange)) {
    if (any(class(model) %in% c("nls", "glm")))
      xrange <- range(model$model[[xvar]])
    else if (any(class(model) %in% "loess"))
      xrange <- range(model$x)
  }
  newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(xrange[1],xrange[2], length.out = samples))
  names(newdata) <- xvar
  newdata[[yvar]] <- predict(model, newdata = newdata, ...)
  newdata
}
```

to form prediction lines that have the same x range across all groups

```
predvals<- ldply(fit, .fun=predictvals, xvar="V", yvar="value",xrange=range(df_new$V))
predvals$xx <- rep(rep(unique(df_new$xx),each=1),each=10)
```

and finally plot with `facet_wrap~xx`

```
ggplot(df_new,aes(y=value,x=V, col=factor(xx)))+
  geom_point(size=3,alpha=.4)+
  geom_line(data=predvals,aes(col=factor(xx)))+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1),limits = c(1e-6,1))+
  facet_wrap(~xx,scales="free_x")
```

[image]

### why there is only one fitting line. I expect two fitting line since I have two subset of data for each `xx` value. Which part I'm missing? any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: you probably need an additional grouping in aes, but your code isn;t reproducible.  `As` and `Ax` aren't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another grouping factor to the `aes` call in `geom_line`.

```
... +
geom_line(data=predvals,aes(col=factor(xx), group=interaction(xx, No))) +
...
```

I haven't looked through the details of your code, so let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: yeap that's what I looked for. I never thought about it anyway. Thanks a lot. Do you think fitting part can be much shorter? since there are many codes..

Comment: The way you've done it looks good to me.  You could do it without the predictvals function to shorten it, but the function is useful and keeps things organized.